# Oracle Connections cannot connect

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created an oracle connection called localDB. I am able to connect to it and create tables, users etc... using the SYS user. 
I created a new user called RTT with password RTT (making sure of the case sensitivity), I granted all roles to this user. However when i try to connect to my localDB with this user i am getting the error message invalid username/password.

What am I doing wrong?
thanks
Edit: See below screenshot for the properties of my connection. If i try to connect with my user RTT with default role then I get the same error message
[image]
[image]

Comment: Either your password is wrong or you have AS SYSDBA set on your connection properties

Comment: Maybe you created the user in the CDB, but are trying to connect to the PDB?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I am an Oracle newbie so do not know how to check connection properties?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I created the user via SQLDeveloper and i am trying to connect via SQLdeveloper too. I dont know Oracle at all

Comment: This page should walk you through the connection details. Maybe edit your question and add a screenshot of the details for your RTT user's connection?  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-0DE0C9F4-8800-4142-A755-14B2FAA6624F.htm#ADMQS12420

Comment: right click on your connection, select properties. What do you have set for Role? It should be set to 'default' and not 'SYSDBA'

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, if i set to username SYS and role to default then i get the error message "ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER". If I set to username RTT and role to default then i get the error "ORA-01017: invalid unserame/pwd"

Comment: @kfinity, see the connection details and my earliest comment about the error message i am getting

Comment: Then you're either connecting to the wrong database, or you're using the wrong password

Comment: When you connect as sysdba, try running `select con_id, name from v$pdbs;` and maybe also `select username, account_status from dba_users where username = 'RTT'`